# /var/log/syslog.1 => 60GB | I seem to have stopped the cause, but don't know how to cleanly deal with the size of the logfile

Tags: logging, systemd, journaling

So basically there is a command (`gotop-cjbassi`) I run continuously for monitoring purposes which started to misbehave badly apparently. After verification, every time it is run, `systemd-journald` writes this line continuously in `/var/log/syslog` :

```
Apr 28 00:13:16 myHostName kernel: [46316.136892] audit: type=1400 audit(1588025596.856:20376494): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gotop-cjbassi.gotop-cjbassi" name="/proc/286/cmdline" pid=101679 comm="ps" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

and `syslog.1` accounts for 65GB (basically all the room left on the filesystem) currently.

Many threads I've seen on the web ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/2me2st/can_i_delete_varcache_and_varlog/), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do)) tells about `logrotate` but no one explains how to use it simply to handle these kind of situation. (Don't even really understand what a "rotation" mean, does it simply compress the files but keep all the data ? If so, that wouldn't be a solution)

I've tried reading the manual a bit but it's really really not user-friendly. Anyway I attempted this command after `cd`-ing into `/var/log` :

```
logrotate -f syslog.1
```

Supposedly to force the rotation. The command seemed to have run successfully. But no size change.

Can I just `cat /dev/null > syslog.1` ?

If so, I would really rather do that : `sed -i '/cjbassi/d' ./syslog.1` but I tried it and `sed` apparently stores a temp file with information about what to delete before deleting it. So that prevents me from running this command successfully since it needs to store a size of the same order of magnitude than the original file meaning several GB more which my filesystem can't handle since I'm already full

Answer (score 0):

If the file is called `syslog.1`, it already was rotated. The currently in-use log file would be `syslog`.

If you don’t need it, just delete it. If you do still need it, you can compress it, but that also requires free space. Because the file should compress very well, you could try with a `tmpfs` (RAM-backed).

If you delete the file and the space is not freed, someone still has the file open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can `> /var/log/syslog.1` if you don't care about what's in the log file.

If you do care about the other contents of the file you can `grep -v snap.gotop-cjbassi.gotop-cjbassi > /var/log/syslogtemp && > /var/log/syslog.1 && mv /var/log/syslogtemp /var/log/syslog.1` if you have enough free space for your regular log lines.

Logrotate settings are found in /etc/logrotate.conf and /etc/logrotate.d/*

In your case the relevant settings will probably be in /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog and look somewhat like this:

```
{
  rotate 7
  daily
  missingok
  notifempty
  delaycompress
  compress
  postrotate
    /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
  endscript
}
```

Because of the option 'delaycompress' logrotate will rotate syslog to syslog.1 without compressing. Next time logrotate runs it will move syslog to syslog.1 and compress syslog.1 to syslog.2.gz  . The compress will of course fail if you don't have enough diskspace for the resulting gz file.

Comment: When a log file, which is basically a glorified text file, gets this big, it becomes useless anyway, in any OS, under any form. Who's is going to check a line in this log among thousands upon thousands of lines, for an event that took place last year on your birthday? Seriously. There's something wrong with the way this log is built, and rotating or compressing it won't change that. You've got to find the, er, root of the problem. My advice: delete this log file, after copying the top hundred lines, maybe, and start afresh.